# ASP.net - Static site search

Tags: asp.net

We have a static website in asp.net with about 50 pages and need to implement a site search. Any suggestions/links will be appreciated.

Thanks,
K

Comment: From the ASP.Net website - http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/email-and-search

Answer (score 4):

If you're looking for a quick way to get search functionality into your pre-existing, static, site, [google site search](http://www.google.com/sitesearch/) would be a very simple route to go.

Answer (score 1):

This link might help you.http://www.codeproject.com/KB/applications/SearchDotnet.aspx  or you can can use sitesearch component for asp.net sites 
http://www.sitesearchasp.net/ 
http://www.asp.net/community/control-gallery/browse.aspx?category=45

Answer (score 0):

I add one more suggestion here.

The UltimateSearch from Karamasoft, that is a commercial product, but you avoid the advertise and have more control over.

http://www.karamasoft.com/UltimateSearch/Features.aspx

Comment: Here is what we did. We reused a small crawler and parsed all content into a simple table in MS SQL database and used MSSQLs Full Text Search to show the results and sorted by relevance. Hope this helps someone.